# Is it possible to reload compiler plugins in Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, compilation

I am creating a small compiler plugin in Vim and I'm finding very slow to debug it.
It seems like there are ways to debug the errorformat but some times I just want to force Vim to reload my compiler plugin that I created in `~/.vim/after/compiler/`

It doesn't look like I can just source the file as it fails because of `CompilerSet`. Is there any other way of reloading a compiler plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply running `:compiler {name}` should reload your full compiler script.

See [`:help :compiler`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler) with the details of how a compiler plug-in is loaded.

An alternative is to source the compiler plug-in file directly. In order to handle the `:CompilerSet` command, you can either define the user command yourself before you run the plug-in file, or use a snippet in your plug-in file itself to define it if not defined already.

Many of the compiler plug-ins shipped with Vim include this snippet at the top:

```
if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2      " older Vim always used :setlocal
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif
```

So apparently that's all you need...

But using `:compiler {name}` each time to fully source it should be a better approach, assuming that's a possibility to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never thought of doing that and solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

(Tangentially) I find tpope’s [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin to have many benefits when working on a vim plugin (and also when writing answers to vim questions where I have to dig deep into runtime files).

Highlights:

- `:PP` is both a pretty-printer and a repl
- `:Runtime` helps reload files
- `:Breakadd` is much smarter
- `:Vedit` and cousins open up files on the runtime path